# Html to xmlParser

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm importing xml content to database via xmlPullParser.
BUT If xml file contains html tags , xmlParser errors.

- In XML file;  Using **&lt ;** and **&gt ;** instead of **<** and **>** works
- Is it possible to use html tags( like < and > ) in xml file directly ?
- If not, how to solve this problem ? Will I need to convert all "<" to  "**&lt ;**" ...etc

  Error: XmlPullParserException: Illegal: "<" inside attribute value

In XML file:

> ```
> // DOESN'T WORK
>  <sample
> note= "<b>Text</b>"
>  />
>
>  // WORKS
> <sample
> note= "&lt;b&gt; Text &lt;/b&gt; "      
> />
> ```

Comment: You might wish to explain **completely and precisely** what "xmlParser errors" you are encountering. You might also wish to explain **completely and precisely** what XML parsers you have tried. Other than the rogue space in the element name (`<sample >` should be `<sample>`), your "DOESN'T WORK" appears to be valid XML.

Comment: While HTML is *not* valid xml in general, the <b>...</b> tags you added are, so adding them to a valid XML should yield again a valid XML. More likely your document contains one or more unclosed tags (like unpaired <p> or one or more <br/>)...

Comment: Error: `XmlPullParserException: Illegal: "<" inside attribute value`. The xml document doesnt have unclosed tags. Using `&lt;` instead of `<` solves problems ! but I dont want to convert all html tags like this.

Comment: "Illegal: "<" inside attribute value" -- since the XML you show does not contain any attributes, this error is not coming from the XML you have in your question.

Comment: I modified question: using &lt;b&gt; instead of <b> ... solves problem !

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear where your problem comes from (as noted in the comments, your **...** tags are xml-ok), regardless here are my two cents: if you need a xml document that can be easily shown on most browsers (or a html file that can be easily parsed) I'd advise you not to waste time on reinventing the wheel trying to coerce HTML into XML, but to try XHTML instead:

[XHTML (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#Cross-compatibility_of_XHTML_and_HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose,my student.xml file which is located in assets folder like,

```
<students>
    <student id="11">
        <roll>1</roll>
        <name>sachin</name>
        <result>pass</result>
    </student>
    <student id="12">
        <roll>2</roll>
        <name>sehwag</name>
        <result>pass</result>
    </student>
    <student id="13">
        <roll>3</roll>
        <name>rohit</name>
        <result>fail</result>
    </student>
</students>
```

Write down the code on button Onclick :

```
try {

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            xpp.setInput(getAssets().open("student.xml"), null);
            int event = xpp.getEventType();

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (event == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

                } else if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    tname = xpp.getName();
                    if (tname.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {
                        str += xpp.getAttributeValue(0).toString() + " : ";

                    }

                } else if (event == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

                } else if (event == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

                    if (tname.equalsIgnoreCase("roll")) {
                        str += xpp.getText();
                        // event = xpp.next();
                    } else if (tname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                        str += xpp.getText();
                        // event = xpp.next();
                    } else if (tname.equalsIgnoreCase("result")) {
                        str += xpp.getText();
                        // event = xpp.next();
                    }

                }
                event = xpp.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv.setText(str);
    }
```